# How can I upload images to a web server, a database, and display the image via a query?

Tags: php, database

I am creating sort of an inventory management system. The functionality I am currently working on is adding inventory images and other info to the database, the web server, and providing a client side view of the current inventory with the uploaded images. Currently, I can only upload images to the web server when adding new inventory. It adds a row to the database with all of the information entered other than the image file path, which is preventing me from being able to retrieve the image and display it on the web page.

This is the php file to add new inventory:

```
<?php 

//Add Apparel Form
echo "<div><h1>Add New Apparel</h1></div>";

    echo "<form action='addNewApparel.php' name='addApparel' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post'>";

    echo "Select Category<span style='color:red'>*</span>: ";
    echo "<select name='category' required>";
        echo "<option value='' disabled selected></option>";
        echo "<option value='T-Shirt'>T-Shirt</option>";
        echo "<option value='Polo'>Polo</option>";
        echo "<option value='Button Up'>Button Up</option>";
        echo "<option value='1/4 Zip'>1/4 Zip</option>";
    echo "</select>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Description:<span style='color:red'>*</span> ";
    echo "<input type='textbox' name='description' required>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Cost:<span style='color:red'>*</span> $ ";
    echo "<input type='textbox' name='unitCost' placeholder='0.00' required>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "XS Quantity: ";
    echo "<input type='number' name='xsQuantity' min = '0' value='0'>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "S Quantity: ";
    echo "<input type='number' name='sQuantity' min = '0' value='0'>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "M Quantity: ";
    echo "<input type='number' name='mQuantity' min = '0' value='0'>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "L Quantity: ";
    echo "<input type='number' name='lQuantity' min = '0' value='0'>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "XL Quantity: ";
    echo "<input type='number' name='xlQuantity' min = '0' value='0'>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "XXL Quantity: ";
    echo "<input type='number' name='xxlQuantity' min = '0' value='0'>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "XXXL Quantity: ";
    echo "<input type='number' name='xxxlQuantity' min = '0' value='0'>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<input type='file' name='apparelImage' onchange='loadFile(event)'>";
    echo "<img id='apparelImage' name='apparelImage' src='http://placehold.it/150/?           text=Choose+File' width='150' height='150'>";
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "<input type='submit' id='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>";

    echo "</form>";

    echo "<button><a href='addInventoryMenu.php'>Back</a></button>";

    //Connect to DB
    require_once("connect.php");

    //Define POST variables
    $category = $_POST["category"];
    $description = $_POST["description"];
    $unitCost = $_POST["unitCost"];
    $xsQuantity = $_POST["xsQuantity"];
    $sQuantity = $_POST["sQuantity"];
    $mQuantity = $_POST["mQuantity"];
    $lQuantity = $_POST["lQuantity"];
    $xlQuantity = $_POST["xlQuantity"];
    $xxlQuantity = $_POST["xxlQuantity"];
    $xxxlQuantity = $_POST["xxxlQuantity"];
    $newFileName= $_POST["apparelImage"];

    //Query to insert data into DB on form submission
    $query = "INSERT INTO `Apparel` (`category`, `description`, `unitCost`, `xsQuantity`, `sQuantity`, `mQuantity`, `lQuantity`, `xlQuantity`, `xxlQuantity`, `xxxlQuantity`, `apparelImage`) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $category)."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$description)."', '$unitCost', '$xsQuantity', '$sQuantity', '$mQuantity', '$lQuantity', '$xlQuantity', '$xxlQuantity', '$xxxlQuantity', '$newFileName')";

    //Verify successful database connection and query execution
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    //Error Handling
    if($result) {
        echo "";
    } else {
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            die("Unsuccessful connection to database: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }

    //Upload Images to Image Folder
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $file = $_FILES['apparelImage']['file'];
        $fileName = $_FILES['apparelImage']['name'];
        $fileTmp = $_FILES['apparelImage']['tmp_name'];
        $fileError = $_FILES['apparelImage']['error'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['apparelImage']['type'];

        $fileExtension = explode('.', $fileName);
        $actualFileExtension = strtolower(end($fileExtension));

        $allowedExtensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

        if(in_array($actualFileExtension, $allowedExtensions)) {
            if ($fileError === 0) {
                $newFileName = uniqid('', true).".".$actualFileExtension;
                $fileDestination = '/export/home/business/'.$fileName;

                move_uploaded_file($fileTmp, $fileDestination);

                header("Location: addNewApparel.php?success");
            } else {
                echo "There was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Please upload a photo with a file name with an extension of .jpg, .jpeg, or .png.";
        }
    }

?>
```

This is the php file to view the inventory:

```
    <?php
    //Connect to DB
    require_once("connect.php");

    //Query to display items
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `Apparel`";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    echo "<div><h1>Current Inventory</h1></div>";

    echo "<div>";
        echo "<a href='viewApparel.php'><button>Apparel</button></a>";
        echo "<a href='viewItems.php'><button>Items</button></a>";
        echo "<a href='viewMarketingMaterials.php'><button>Marketing Material</button></a>";
        echo "<button><a href='inventoryIndex.php'>Back</a></button>";  

    echo "</div>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Category</th>";
            echo "<th>Description</th>";
            echo "<th>Unit Cost</th>";
            echo "<th>XS Quantity</th>";
            echo "<th>S Quantity</th>";
            echo "<th>M Quantity</th>";
            echo "<th>L Quantity</th>";
            echo "<th>XL Quantity</th>";
            echo "<th>XXL Quantity</th>";
            echo "<th>XXXL Quantity</th>";
            echo "<th>Image</th>";
        echo "</tr>";

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>{$row['category']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['description']}</td>";
            echo "<td>$ {$row['unitCost']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['xsQuantity']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['sQuantity']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['mQuantity']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['lQuantity']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['xlQuantity']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['xxlQuantity']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$row['xxxlQuantity']}</td>";
            echo "<td><img src='{$row['apparelImage']}' width='150' height='150'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    echo "<button><a href='inventoryIndex.php'>Back</a></button>";

    //Error Handling
    if($result) {
        echo "";
    } else {
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            die("Unsuccessful connection to database: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }
?>
```

I know this is a lot, but some help would be great, as I'm pretty sure I'm close to getting this figured out!

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? What **exactly** is not working - uploading files, retrieving them,....?

Comment: Uploading files to web server works. I want the user's file name for the image to appear in the database as apparelImage for each row, which is currently not happening. Does this help?

Comment: Why is that not happening? Is the data stored properly? If not: debug the steps where you write data to the database.  If that is stored properly, is there an issue with the markup for displaying that image?

Comment: The only process that I don't have right is with the SQL query to insert the image path into the database. I'm able to retrieve the images properly. I know this because I manually entered a file path in to see if I was retrieving the image correctly.

Comment: Your question is not so clear for me, but if you want create a file with the username logged for the image in the database, a idea would be pass the username as parameter to the code (is php?) where the insert sql query runs.

So, inside the sql query you would put a variable with the username, something like: $insert_query = "INSERT INTO Mytable (Filename)
VALUES ('".$username."');"